# AWS RDS "Publicly Accessible = No" vs instance in private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, subnet, private-subnet

I am creating infrastructure for one of my web application on AWS. That app needs Mysql RDS instance. Now I am wondering that whether I should simply create RDS instance in public subnet and just change its settings to Publicly Accessible=No, or I will have to create this RDS instance in private subnet for better security or something. I am confused that whether any of above option will provide better security than other.

I have also read that simply assigning security group to instance will act as firewall, so I can have publicly accessible=true RDS instance and its security group allowing access only from my application EC2 instance. So basically I have three options mentioned below.

1. Publicly Accessible = True RDS instance in public subnet with security group allowing access only to EC2 application instance.
2. Publicly Accessible = False RDS instance in public subnet.
3. RDS instance in private subnet.

Can anyone explain pros and cons in terms of security for above approaches?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct that Security Groups can provide sufficient protection for your database, and also for Amazon EC2 instances.

So why does AWS provide public/private subnets? It's because many customers want them because that is how enterprises typically organise their network prior to using the cloud. Traditional firewalls only act *between subnets*, whereas Security Groups apply *to each instance individually*.

So, if you understand how to correctly configure Security Groups, there is **no actual need to use Private Subnets at all!** Some people, however, feel more comfortable putting resources in private subnets because it provides an additional layer of security.

Comment: Would communicating with an RDS instance through a public endpoint incur more data transfer costs vs one that doesn't have one?

Comment: @LLL Please create a new question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.

Comment: Sorry, I made one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59306308/rds-data-transger-costs-public-vs-private-endpoints