# RDS data transfer costs public vs private endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

Would communicating with an RDS instance through a public endpoint (RDS in a public subnet) incur more data transfer costs vs one in a private subnet, given that both RDS and the entity accessing it are in the same AZ?

Comment: Are you accessing RDS from an Amazon EC2 instance in the same VPC?

Comment: From a lambda in the same VPC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **DNS Name** of the Amazon RDS db instance should resolve to a private IP address when used within the VPC. Thus, the only potential charge is **2¢/GB between AZs** (1¢ in and 1¢ out).

If they are both in the **same AZ**, there should be no data transfer charge.

Accessing via a public IP address would incur 1¢/GB, but this does not doubly-charge with the "between AZ" charge. So, same potential cost.

If accessing the RDS instance from the Internet, then additional Data Transfer charges would apply for *outbound* data.